# App stops working once deployed to Meteor.com?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I built a weather app that gets data from the forecast.io api and the flickr api after geocoding a location. It works fine when I'm running it locally. I deployed it to meteor.com (http://betterweather.meteor.com).

And.... it doesn't work. I can enter a location and click search, and nothing happens. In the console, it says there was an exception in delivering the result of getForecastData and getFlickrPhotos, the two methods that I call to retrieve data from the apis. But I can't figure out why that would happen once deployed and not happen locally?

The only thing I could possibly think of is that my API keys are in a settings file, so normally when I run the app locally I have to start it with meteor --settings settings.json. Could that have something to do with it?

Below is an example of what I'm seeing in the console:

"Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getFlickrPhotos': ["submit form"] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've identified the problem. You can deploy to Meteor with a flag to include a settings file:

`meteor deploy betterweather.meteor.com --settings settings.json`

See if that solves it.

Comment: That seems to have done it! Still have some issues to fix, but at least it basically works now.